# How to read csv in Impala which has fields within double quotes consisting delimiter

Tags: impala

If I am trying to create impala external table over cab file which is pipe delimited and there are few columns where are enclosed within "" double quotes also contains delimiter | pipe , so how can I do it.

Serde is not supported in impala.
Is there any other way to do ? Please find sample data below

123|Abhijit|"||a|b|"

Answer (score 0):

You can load cab files into hdfs via the file browser. You can then read from hdfs and specify your separators for the given file - in this case, your separator would be the pipe. Using the following statement relevant to your file should work fine:

```
CREATE [EXTERNAL] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS]
db_name.table_name

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED BY '|'

LOCATION 'hdfs_path'
```

Here the location is simply the location of your cab file within hdfs.

Comment: But it will seggreagte the column which has delimiter as part of its values.

Answer (score 0):

Do not surround string values with quotation marks in text data files that you construct. If you need to include the separator character inside a field value, for example to put a string value with a comma inside a CSV-format data file, specify an escape character on the CREATE TABLE statement with the ESCAPED BY clause, and insert that character immediately before any separator characters that need escaping(in your text file).

https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_txtfile.html